# Perl FTP uploading empty file to server

Tags: perl, upload, ftp

I have to upload a file to a Debian server using Perl and FTP. I tried `$ftp->put` which gave me no errors but uploaded only an empty file (or created one), and `$ftp->copy` which gave me some weird message, I guess is an error and again, an empty file.

My file is located in `/home/upload`

Debug from put:

```
Upload file to FTP? (y/n): y
Net::FTP>>> Net::FTP(2.77)
Net::FTP>>>   Exporter(5.64_03)
Net::FTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.29)
Net::FTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.31)
Net::FTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.32)
Net::FTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.31)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)<<< 220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)>>> USER upload
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)<<< 331 Please specify the password.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)>>> PASS ....
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)<<< 230 Login successful.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)>>> CWD /home/upload/uploaded/
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)<<< 250 Directory successfully changed.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)>>> PORT 127,0,0,1,212,114
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)<<< 200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)>>> STOR file.txt
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)<<< 150 Ok to send data.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0xa7bdf30)<<< 226 Transfer complete.
```

Debug from copy:

```
Upload file to FTP? (y/n): y
Net::FTP>>> Net::FTP(2.77)
Net::FTP>>>   Exporter(5.64_03)
Net::FTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.29)
Net::FTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.31)
Net::FTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.32)
Net::FTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.31)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> USER upload
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 331 Please specify the password.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> PASS ....
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 230 Login successful.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> CWD /home/upload/uploaded/
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 250 Directory successfully changed.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> PWD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 257 "/home/upload/uploaded"
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> HELP SIZE
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 214-The following commands are recognized.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<<  ABOR ACCT ALLO APPE CDUP CWD  DELE EPRT EPSV FEAT HELP LIST MDTM MKD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<<  MODE NLST NOOP OPTS PASS PASV PORT PWD  QUIT REIN REST RETR RMD  RNFR
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<<  RNTO SITE SIZE SMNT STAT STOR STOU STRU SYST TYPE USER XCUP XCWD XMKD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<<  XPWD XRMD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 214 Help OK.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> SIZE /home/file.txt
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 213 0
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> PWD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 257 "/home/upload/uploaded"
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> CWD /home/file.txt
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 550 Failed to change directory.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> CWD /home/upload/uploaded
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 250 Directory successfully changed.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> PWD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 257 "/home/upload/uploaded"
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> PORT 127,0,0,1,161,36
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> RETR /home/file.txt
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /home/file.txt (0 bytes).
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 226 Transfer complete.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> PORT 127,0,0,1,233,200
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)>>> STOR copied.txt
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x9f45f48)<<< 150 Ok to send data.
write($buf,$size,[$timeout]) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Net/FTP/File.pm line 128
```

Relevant code:

```
sub write_file(){
    my $file = $savefile;
    if($file ne "" && $file ne "\n"){
            open(DATA, ">$file") || die(print("I cannot save to the file [$file]"));
            print("Created file [$file]\r\nWriting data to file. Please be patient...");
            foreach(@file){
                    print DATA $_ . "\r\n";
                    $indexer++;
                    print ".\b";
            }

            print("\r\n\r\nFinished! $indexer lines written to file.\r\n");

            print("Upload file to FTP? (y/n): ");
            my $yn = <STDIN>;
            if(lc($yn) eq "y\n"){
                    my $ftp = Net::FTP->new("127.0.0.1",Timeout=>250, Debug => 1) or die "Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1: $@";
                    $ftp->login("upload",'ftp') or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;
                    my $file_to_put = $file;
                    my $dir = "/home/upload/uploaded/";
                    $ftp->cwd($dir) or die "Can't cwd to $dir\n";


                    #$ftp->put($file_to_put) or die "Can't put $file into $dir\n";
                    #if (! $ftp->put($file_to_put)) {
                    if (! $ftp->copy($file_to_put, "copied.txt", 1000)) {
                            my $ftp_message = $ftp->message;
                            chomp($ftp_message);
                            print "[Error] UNABLE TO PUT FILE $file_to_put- [$ftp_message]\n";
                    }

                    #$ftp->quit;
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: Looks like the file on local system has zero byte `/home/file.txt (0 bytes).` Are you sure that is the correct file?

Comment: @Jens It is 7770 Bytes long actually, it contains CSV data

Comment: You are looking on the same file?

Comment: @Jens I could upload a picture if you wish, but in my Perl script I create a file containing data, and in the same script i try and upload it to FTP. But I'll add some more code so you can see.

Comment: If you created it in the same script make sure you have closed the file before transfer it.

Comment: @Jens You are a genious my good Sir! Thank you! That did in fact help.

Comment: I am not a genious. I made the same error many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close the strem befor transfer it to the remote host:

```
open(DATA, ">$file") || die(print("I cannot save to the file [$file]"));

        print("Created file [$file]\r\nWriting data to file. Please be patient...");
        foreach(@file){
                print DATA $_ . "\r\n";
                $indexer++;
                print ".\b";
        }
 close(DATA);
```